# elfeed and emacs 27: elfeed-db-load: Wrong type argument

Tags: elfeed

After upgrading to emacs 27 with

```
brew install emacs --HEAD
```

When starting elfeed with

```
C-x w
```

I get

```
elfeed-db-load: Wrong type argument: avl-tree-, [cl-struct-avl-tree- [[[[[[[[[[[[[nil nil ... 0] [nil nil ... 0]\
 ... 0] [[nil nil ... 0] [nil nil ... 0] ... 0] ... 0] [[[nil nil ... 0] [nil nil ... 0] ... 0] [nil [nil nil ..\
. 0] ... 1] ... 0] ... 0] [[[[nil nil ... 0] nil ... -1] [[nil nil ... 0] [nil nil ... 0] ... 0] ... 0] [[[nil n\
il ... 0] [nil nil ... 0] ... 0] [[nil nil ... 0]
...   -1] nil nil 0] elfeed-db-compare]
```

Any ideas how to make elfeed work? This used to work in emacs 25

Comment: I don't use `elfeed`, but usually incompatibilities in underlying data types and macros from version to version can be solved by recompiling the source. Have you tried reinstalling elfeed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this

rm ~/.emacs.d/elpa/elfeed-20180115.2112/*.elc

Comment: Better yet: `M-x package-reinstall RET elfeed RET`.

Answer (score 0):

It is problem with the elfeed-db after the emacs internals have changed in v. 26. See https://github.com/skeeto/elfeed/issues/207.

The database needs to be rebuild. I ran `rm -rf ~/.elfeed/` and restarted emacs to purge memory.